# Homeomorphism sends disjoint sets to disjoint sets

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Just want to confirm my intuition... if $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, and $U,V\in X$ are disjoint open sets in $X$, then $f(U)$ is disjoint from $f(V)$?

Comment: That is already true for an injective function.

Comment: You don't mean $U,V \in X.$

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is a homeomorphism then it is namely a bijection, so is one-to-one. Then if $f(U)$ was not disjoint from $f(V)$ we have some $u \in U$ and $v \in V$ such that $f(u) = x = f(v)$. However since $U$ and $V$ are disjoint we have $u \neq v$, so $f$ is not one-to-one, a contradiciton.